# How to perform advanced Sub Document Queries in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, database-schema

I have a Schema(Case) which has an array of Sub Schema(Assessment).

My Case Schema is as follows:

```
const caseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    patient: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Password can\'t be empty' 
    }
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Case description can\'t be empty'
    },
    assessments: [assessmentSchema]
});
```

My Assessment Schema is as follows

```
const assessmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    doctor: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Doctor can\'t be empty'
    },
    doa: Date,
    slots: String
});
```

My problem here is to find all the assessment documents in the entire collection(where the doctor and doa is specified). But as these details are available only in the Sub Schema, I have no idea on how to approach this problem. And I also cannot add a doctor field to the Case Schema as there might be many doctors in a case. I'm using mongoose. I searched many places on the internet and was not able to arrive at a solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this.

This is an aggregate where `$project` stage is used to pass the documents with the requested fields.
The fields that pass to the next phase are the ones that match the filter.
Into the filter we use `$eq` condition to check 'doctor' and 'slots' fields.

Note that you have to use `$` operator, that is the positional operator.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "assessments": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$assessments",
          "as": "ass",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$ass.doctor",
              "doctor1"
            ],
            "$eq": [
              "$$ass.slots",
              "slots1"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is a Playground [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ly1TCLTpWkA)

Edit: With this new query you can get all fields you want.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "patient": 1,
      "description": 1,
      "assessments": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$assessments",
          "as": "as",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$as.doctor",
              "doctor1"
            ],
            "$eq": [
              "$$as.slots",
              "slots1"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Note there is only a little difference.
Into `$project` you can decide what fields you want to show/reset/... [reference $project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

So adding `caseSchema` into query fields do the works.

Comment: What should I do to include the patient field(caseSchema) in the result? Thank you so much

Comment: Hi, I've updated the answer. Is so easy, only indicate fields you want to show as '1' below ```$project```.

Comment: You are welcome! Please, if it accomplish your requirements, set the answer to accepted.